# Can Scanner be temporarily disabled?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

In my Java program, the user is presented with a String for 5 seconds (Thread.sleep(5000)). Then the console is cleared (\f), and they are asked to reproduced the string (using Scanner.nextLine). The problem is that they can enter their answer before the console is cleared. Is there anyway I can stop the Scanner from taking input for 5 seconds?

Comment: Please add the code of your java program

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding correctly what you're referring to, this isn't a feature of the Scanner. It's a feature of the console, which [buffers keyboard input](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_buffer). You can't stop it except by writing a GUI program, and not using the console.